# JSON - UICollectionView

Tags: ios, json, uitableview, swift3, uicollectionview

sorry for asking, but i realy dont know what else to try.

i'm trying to parse json into a collection view but it wont get the info, no error is shown in console.
I have the same parser working into a tableView. What am i missing??
Can someone point me in the right direction?

This is the controler for the collectionView:

```
//


import UIKit
import SVProgressHUD
import TSMessages
import SDWebImage

class collectionController: UIViewController {


    @IBOutlet weak var collectionView: UICollectionView!

    var articles = [Article]()


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()


        guard Helper.hasInternetConnection() else {
            TSMessage.showNotification(withTitle: "Por favor verifique a sua ligação à Internet", type: .error)
            return

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

      SVProgressHUD.show()
        WebServices.getArticles { (success, message, items) in
            SVProgressHUD.dismiss()

            guard success != false
                else {
                    TSMessage.showNotification(withTitle: message, type: .error)

                return
            }

            guard items != nil
                else {
                    TSMessage.showNotification(withTitle: "NO ARTICLES", type: .error)
                    return
            }
            self.articles = items!
            self.collectionView.reloadData()

        }
    }

}
    /*
    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if (segue.identifier == "moreDetails") {
            let vc2 = segue.destination as! MoreDetailsViewController
            vc2.article = sender as! Article
        }
    }
 */extension collectionController: UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource {

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
            collectionView.deselectItem(at: indexPath, animated: true)
            performSegue(withIdentifier: "moreDetails", sender: self.articles[indexPath.item])
        }



    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cells = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)
        as! ArticleCell2

        cells.title2.text = self.articles[indexPath.item].headline.cleanHtml
        cells.desc2.text = self.articles[indexPath.item].desc.html2String.cleanHtml
        cells.imgView2.sd_setImage(with: URL(string: self.articles[indexPath.item].imageUrl!))

print(cells)
        return cells
    }

    func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }


    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

        return self.articles.count

    }
}
```

this one for the tableView (working great):

```
import UIKit
import SVProgressHUD
import TSMessages
import SDWebImage

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var tableview: UITableView!

    var articles = [Article]()


    // MARK:
    // MARK: - Lifecycle

    override func viewDidLoad() {

        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.title = "Artigos"


        self.tableview.tableFooterView = UIView(frame: CGRect.zero)

        guard Helper.hasInternetConnection() else {
            TSMessage.showNotification(withTitle: "Por favor verifique a sua ligação à Internet", type: .error)
            return
        }

        SVProgressHUD.show()

        WebServices.getArticles { (success, message, items) in

            SVProgressHUD.dismiss()

            guard success != false else {
                TSMessage.showNotification(withTitle: message, type: .error)
                return
            }

            guard items != nil else {
                TSMessage.showNotification(withTitle: "Não existem artigos.", type: .error)
                return
            }

            self.articles = items!
            self.tableview.reloadData()
        }
    }

    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {

        if (segue.identifier == "moreDetails") {
            let vc = segue.destination as! MoreDetailsViewController
            vc.article = sender as! Article
        }
    }
}

// MARK:
// MARK: - UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource

extension ViewController: UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "moreDetails", sender: self.articles[indexPath.row])
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "articleCell", for: indexPath) as! ArticleCell

        cell.title.text = self.articles[indexPath.item].headline.cleanHtml
        cell.desc.text = self.articles[indexPath.item].desc.html2String.cleanHtml
        cell.author.text = self.articles[indexPath.item].author.cleanHtml
        cell.imgView.sd_setImage(with: URL(string: self.articles[indexPath.item].imageUrl!))

        return cell
    }

    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return self.articles.count
    }



}
```

[storyboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sSJJW.png)

Comment: Did you assign the delegate? (Assuming in Storyboard).

Comment: yes everything is linked properly. If i do a print (cell) in the func it doesn't return anything.. like it seems it doesn't get to that point

Comment: try to reload `collectionView` in main thread after getting API response.